# elasticsearch nested multi_field not_analyzed not working

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, mapping, facet

I'm having a problem for hours now that I just don't get solved.

I need to do a facets search to get a list of all videos playlists.

A video can have more than one playlists, which each "name", "position". That's why it is nested.

Here is my mapping:

```
{
   "mappings" : {
    "test" : {
         "properties" : {
             "playlists": {
                 "type": "nested",
                 "properties" : {
                     "name" : {
                         "type": "multi_field",
                         "fields" : {
                             "name": {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "store": "yes"},
                             "untouched" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                         }
                     },
                     "position" : {
                         "type" : "string"
                     }
                 }
             }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

The problem is the name when it contains a "-". For example "de-classic" with the following facets search:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "facets": {
    "playlists": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "playlists.name",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My facet search returns one entry for "de" and one for "classic":

```
facets: {
    playlists: {
        _type: terms,
        missing: 0,
        total: 2,
        other: 0,
        terms: [
            {
                term: de
                count: 1
            },
            {
                term: classics
                count: 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I put a simplified gist here: https://gist.github.com/axeff/bacf3bb2119f7589e612

Elasticsearch v1.1.1

**Edit:**

Also the mapping after I insert looks not like the mapping I created:

curl localhost:9200/videos/test/_mapping?pretty=true:

```
{
  "videos" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "test" : {
        "properties" : {
          "playlists" : {
            "properties" : {
              "name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "position" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "facets": {
    "playlists": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "playlists.name",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "nested": "playlists"  // <- that's what I was missing!
    }
  }
}
```